# SQL Server -Open XML with parent child relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-openxml

I have a parent - child XML data. and i want to insert the data in SQL using open xml. 
Customers node will go into customer Table. and the corresponding key generated will go in as foreign key relationship into orders table. How to do this?

```
<Customers  ContactName="Joe" CompanyName="Company1">
  <Orders  OrderDate="2000-08-25T00:00:00"/>
  <Orders  OrderDate="2000-10-03T00:00:00"/>
</Customers>
<Customers  ContactName="Steve" CompanyName="Company2">
  <Orders  OrderDate="2000-10-03T00:00:00"/>

</Customers>
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2005+, it's time to move on to the XML datatype and XPath queries

Answer (score 2):

I assume that identity columns `CustomerID` and `OrderID` are primary keys in your `Customers` and `Orders` tables and that you have `CustomerID` as FK in `Orders`. I use `CustomerName` and `ContactName` to locate the `CustomerID` to use in `Orders.CustomerID`. If there is a chance that the Customer from the XML is already in the Customer table you should exclude those rows from the insert with a `where not exists` clause.

First is a version that uses a XML variable like @Richard suggests in his comment.

```
declare @Customers table (CustomerID int identity, ContactName varchar(50), CompanyName varchar(50))
declare @Orders table (OrderID int identity, CustomerID int, OrderDate datetime)

declare @xml as xml = '
<Customers  ContactName="Joe" CompanyName="Company1">
  <Orders  OrderDate="2000-08-25T00:00:00"/>
  <Orders  OrderDate="2000-10-03T00:00:00"/>
</Customers>
<Customers  ContactName="Steve" CompanyName="Company2">
  <Orders  OrderDate="2000-10-03T00:00:00"/>
</Customers>'

insert into @Customers (ContactName, CompanyName)
select 
  c.value('@ContactName', 'varchar(50)'),
  c.value('@CompanyName', 'varchar(50)')
from @xml.nodes('Customers') as n(c)

;with cteOrders as
(
  select
    o.value('@OrderDate', 'DateTime') as OrderDate,
    o.value('../@ContactName', 'varchar(50)') as ContactName,
    o.value('../@CompanyName', 'varchar(50)') as CompanyName
  from @xml.nodes('Customers/Orders') as n(o)
)
insert into @Orders (CustomerID, OrderDate)
select C.CustomerID, O.OrderDate
from cteOrders as O 
  inner join @Customers as C
    on C.CompanyName = O.CompanyName and
       C.ContactName = O.ContactName
```

The second version uses `openxml`. If you use `openxml` there can only be one root element so I added a root element to your sample XML.

```
declare @Customers table (CustomerID int identity, ContactName varchar(50), CompanyName varchar(50))
declare @Orders table (OrderID int identity, CustomerID int, OrderDate datetime)

declare @xml as xml = '
<root>
  <Customers  ContactName="Joe" CompanyName="Company1">
    <Orders  OrderDate="2000-08-25T00:00:00"/>
    <Orders  OrderDate="2000-10-03T00:00:00"/>
  </Customers>
  <Customers  ContactName="Steve" CompanyName="Company2">
    <Orders  OrderDate="2000-10-03T00:00:00"/>
  </Customers>
</root>'

declare @idoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc out, @XML


insert into @Customers (ContactName, CompanyName)
select C.ContactName, C.CompanyName
from openxml(@idoc, '/root/Customers', 0) with
                    (ContactName varchar(50),
                     CompanyName varchar(50)) as C


insert into @Orders (CustomerID, OrderDate)
select C.CustomerID, OrderDate
from openxml(@idoc, '/root/Customers/Orders', 0) with
          (OrderDate datetime,
             ContactName varchar(50) '../@ContactName',
             CompanyName varchar(50) '../@CompanyName') as O
  inner join @Customers as C
    on C.CompanyName = O.CompanyName and
       C.ContactName = O.ContactName

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```